# nVidia GTX Titan change DP rate?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I bought and installed two EVGA [nVidia GTX Titan](http://www.evga.com/products/pdf/06G-P4-2790.pdf) cards in my Ubuntu 12.04 TS box for HPC. I was disappointed with the benchmark results I got, see [Eigen-Magma](https://github.com/bravegag/eigen-magma-benchmark). I was actually expecting e.g. [DGEMM to deliver about 1.3 TFlop/s](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6774/nvidias-geforce-gtx-titan-part-2-titans-performance-unveiled/3) but instead in my benchmarks it stayed short at [200 GFlop/s with DGEMM](https://raw.github.com/bravegag/eigen-magma-benchmark/master/results/dgemm_gflops.png).

However, after some additional research I learned that it is possible to change the Double Precision (DP) rate of the GTX Titan card to 1/3th of the Single Precision (SP) [see the last section "I'm a cheap Tesla then?" first paragraph](http://hexus.net/tech/reviews/graphics/51857-nvidia-geforce-gtx-titan-6gb-graphics-card-overview/) and that by default the Titan will operate at 1/24th of the possible DP rate which is what I experienced in my benchmarks.

The question is then how can I change the DP rate of a nVidia Titan GTX card on Ubuntu 12.04 TS? I have the latest nVidia drivers installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found the setting that solves the problem, it is to check the `CUDA-Double precision` box in the PowerMizer entry of the `nvidia-settings` tool. I get about 3x better DP performance using CUBLAS. I reach 1.2 TFlop/s using a modified version of the CUDA sample matrixMulCUBLAS that uses DGEMM and therefore the issue is resolved.

[image: nvidia-settings CUDA-Double precision]